# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

I can not for the life of me figure why this is failing, ugly code I know but I just need to put it out for a school project.

```
def changeusername(self,i):
    user="self.user=self.username"+str(i)+".get()"
    exec(user)
    print(self.user)
    record1=list(c.execute("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE usernames=(?)",(self.user)))
    print(record1)
```

I get this error:

```
line 428, in changeusername
record1=list(c.execute("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE usernames=(?)",(self.user)))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied.
```

I have probably missed something really simple but hey :P

EDIT: It seems to work for my single char usernames but it fails when I try the ADMIN username hence the 5 bindings

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pass the argument to `execute()` as a tuple. Replace:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE usernames=(?)", (self.user))
```

with:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE usernames=(?)", (self.user, ))
```