# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 9 supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to use a `input` variable into a `SELECT` statement but getting the error below.

Here is my code:

```
sheetname=input("Enter the name of the SEO Analysis sheet:")
cur=conn.execute("select * from seo_info where url like '%?%'",sheetname,)
print(cur.fetchall())
```

and here is an error:

```
File "E:/Python/SEO_Project2.py", line 40, in <module>
cur=conn.execute("select * from seo_info where url like '%?%'",sheetname,)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 9 supplied.
```

Here is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270534/sqlite3-programmingerror-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-sta), that addresses a part of the issue, but still it is giving me error.

Maybe I am missing a little something in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I did it  !

```
cur=conn.execute("select * from seo_info where url like (?)",['%'+sheetname+'%'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need parentheses around `?`, so you can achieve what you want using `list`, as a second argument to `execute`:

```
cur = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM seo_info WHERE url LIKE ?', ['%' + sheetname + '%'])
```

or `tuple`:

```
cur = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM seo_info WHERE url LIKE ?', ('%' + sheetname + '%'),)
```